# How to print in a specific element in a list in a sorted order in python

Tags: python

I'm tasked to create a function that takes a string filename as an argument, reads the file with the name filename, and prints
all confirmed reservations in order of the time.

A line in the file is formatted like so
name, time, reservation_status (can either be confirmed or canceled in uppercase)

An example of a file "reservations.txt" could look like this:

```
Alex, 20, CONFIRMED
Thomas, 16, CANCELLED
William, 18, CONFIRMED
```

The correct output when calling the function on this example file should look like this:

```
show_reservations("reservations.txt")
>>> William, 18
    Alex, 20
```

My solution:

```
def show_reservations(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.replace(',', '').split()
            status = line[2]
            if status == "CONFIRMED":
                name = line[0]
                time = line[1]
                print(name + ",", time)
```

However, calling my solution on the example file above gives me following output:

```
   show_reservations("reservations.txt")
   >>> Alex, 20
       William, 18
```

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because your original sequence comes in this way:

```
Alex, 20, CONFIRMED
...
William, 18, CONFIRMED
```

So you can save your filtered elements into a list and apply sorting on it. For example using [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) function.

You could try something like this:

```
def show_reservations(filename):
    confirmed_orders = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            line = line.replace(',', '').split()
            name, _time, status = line
            if status == "CONFIRMED":
                confirmed_orders.append((name, _time))
    
    confirmed_orders_by_time = sorted(confirmed_orders, key=lambda x: x[1])

    for name, _time in confirmed_orders_by_time:
        print(name + ",", _time)
```

Also several additional suggestions in case the snippet you've provided is a real production code:

1. **time** is a bad name for variable because it can clash with built-in Python's module [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html).
2. **split** gives you tuple, so instead of messing with accessing by index you can unpack it:

   name, _time, status = line
3. This thing `line.replace(',', '').split()` won't work correctly if name or status in the file will have a "space". Consider to use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) or something else for parsing data file.
4. If you use Python 3.5 or higher f-string is a preferable way instead of manual string concatenation:

   print(f"{name}, {_time}")

Answer (score 2):

you don't store your data and you also need some sorting

---

```
def funct(e):
    return e['time']


def show_reservations(filename):
        with open(filename) as f:
            l=[]
            for line in f.readlines():
                line = line.replace(',', '').split()
                dict={}
                status = line[2]
                if status == "CONFIRMED":
                    dict["name"] = line[0]
                    dict["time"] = line[1]
                    name = line[0]
                    time = line[1]
                    l.append(dict)
            l.sort(key=funct)
            for i in l:
                print('{0} , {1}'.format(i["name"],i["time"]))

show_reservations("input.txt")
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def show_reservations(filename):
    reservations = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            splitted_line = line.replace(',', '').split()
            status = splitted_line[2]
            if status == "CONFIRMED":
                time = splitted_line[1]
                name = splitted_line[0]
                reservations.append({"time":time, "name":name})
    return sorted(reservations, key=lambda k: k['time'])

for reservation in show_reservations("reservations.txt"):
    print(reservation["name"] + ",", reservation["time"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly printing, `append` the entries to a list of tuples `(time, name)`. Then after the list, sort it (`li.sort()`), and loop through it again, this time printing.